# weblogic user authentication in java

Tags: authentication, weblogic

in one web application, user will enter login and password. User is created in WebLogic server 10.3

I need to authenticat user in weblogic server. I was searching on google, i found there is some sample code on http://dev.bea.com/code for authentication through JAAS.

I tried to access that web page but it seems page has been removed.

Is there any way to authenticat user entered login password.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if the user is authenticated by weblogic, you don't have to do anything special except configuring your realm in the right way.